# How can I create a new contact from Messages & add it to a specific Group in Contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, contacts

When I receive an SMS message, I can create a new contact from the number. Works great, very useful. Lots of business folks must do the same.

What I want to do is create the contact in my business CardDAV server account, not my personal contacts. There is no option to select Group. So I thought i would get clever, went into Contacts, selected "Hide All Groups" and made only the CardDAV account I want active. The newly minted contact from Messages is still saved in the default-by-virtue-of-being-first-in-the-list" iCloud account.

There is also no good way to do this from the desktop in Messages. Creating a new contact similarly always goes into whatever happens to be first in the list of accounts (order which can't be changed after the account is installed). I can then drag the contact into the appropriate group, finally go back and delete the original. That's too many steps and opportunities for mistakes.

Does anyone have a reasonable workflow to get around this oversight? Or a 3rd party app recommendation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Under the mail options in settings; there is a section for contacts, you will see "default account" change that option to the account you wish to have all your contacts created in.